# How to deploy Django with Channels and Celery on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, celery

How one deploys the following stack on Heroku platform ?

- Django
- Django Channels
- Celery

The limitation surely is on the `Procfile`.

To deploy Django with Celery it would be something like:

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi:application
worker: celery worker --app=project.taskapp --loglevel=info
```

While deploying Django with Channels:

```
web: daphne project.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

The `web` process can use ASGI, but the `worker` process will be used by Channels and I don't see how Celery can be started alongside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have as many entries in the Procfile as you like. The only one that is special is "web", because that's the one Heroku expects to receive web requests, and the only one it will start automatically for you. You can use your own names for the rest:

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi:application
celeryworker: celery worker --app=project.taskapp --loglevel=info
channelsworker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

Now you can do `heroku ps:scale celeryworker=1` and `heroku ps:scale channelsworker=1` to start the other two processes.

See the [Heroku Procfile docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) for more information.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you very much sir.